# mongodb indexing at sub level issue

Tags: mongodb

i have a structure of document in mongodb as below

```
{
  "_id": "some_id",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": [
             {"subkey1":"subval1", "subkey2":"subval2",   "subkey3":"subval3"},
             {"subkey1":"subval11", "subkey2":"subval21", "subkey3":"subval31"},
             {"subkey1":"subval12", "subkey2": "subval22", "subkey3":"subval32"}
            ],
    "key4": "value4"
}
```

and i want to put index on "subkey1". how to do it???

or is it not possible(in this case is it work that much efficiently with the index on "key3")???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [ensureIndex](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) to add an index to the key you want

```
db.foos.ensureIndex({"key3.subkey1": 1})
```

as indicated in [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-IndexingArrayElements):

> When a document's stored value for a index key field is an array, MongoDB indexes each element of the array

adding an index to key3 alone, would not be used if you query using "key3.subkey1".

Comment: ya it was the option in our mind but we have a little bit confusion that will it work for whole array?? like here 3 elements in the array of key3(value part)...so is it going to index all three "subkey1" or not??

Comment: @user yes it does. This is clearly documented though so you should be able to figure out what happens exactly.